# Deserializng objects with cross references into two lists with DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

At first - sorry for my English. I know "loan" and "loaner" are not proper words for this.

I have two classes:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class Person {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string IDK { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public ObservableCollection<Book> CurrentLoanedBooks { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Book>();

        public Person() { 
        }

        public Person(string name, string idk) {
            this.Name = name;
            this.IDK = idk;
        }
    }
```

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Book {
        [DataMember]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string IDC { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Person Loaner { get; set; }

        public Book() {
        }

        public Book(string title, string idc) {
            this.Title = title;
            this.IDC = idc;
        }
    }
```

I also have two lists in my main class:

```
private ObservableCollection<Book> Books { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
private ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
```

My program binds these collections to a DataGrid in WPF. While the program is running user can input new Books as well as new People. The problem is the serialization. I managed to make a `DataContractSerializer` which produces output without any errors. However, I have trouble with loading the data. The deserialization produces good output, I have both lists loaded. But I can't figure out how can I link objects from these two lists with themselves.

The deserialization doesn't link any objects. After deserialization, when I try to see the Book's Loaner I can't see the proper Loaner that was loaded and created in List.

When I save Book Loaner in one variable, and a proper Person in second, the object references do not match.

```
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(loaner2, loaner1));
// False
```

I would like to deserialize it in a way, that will "link" these object with themselves.

Serialization and deserialization:

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    DataContractSerializer b_ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Book>));
    DataContractSerializer p_ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Person>));

    using(FileStream b_fs = File.OpenWrite("books.xml"))
    using(FileStream p_fs = File.OpenWrite("people.xml")) {
        p_ser.WriteObject(b_fs, this.Books);
        p_ser.WriteObject(p_fs, this.People);
    }
}
```

```
private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    DataContractSerializer b_ser = new 
    DataContractSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Book>));
    DataContractSerializer p_ser = new 
    DataContractSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Person>));

    try {
        using (FileStream b_fs = File.OpenRead("books.xml"))
        using (FileStream p_fs = File.OpenRead("people.xml")) {
                this.Books = b_ser.ReadObject(b_fs) as ObservableCollection<Book>;
                this.People = p_ser.ReadObject(p_fs) as ObservableCollection<Person>;
        }
    } catch (...) {
        // Setting default values if some trouble
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, add code how you serialize and deserialize your collections. The problem is somewhere there. `DataContractSerializer` is able to save and resolve references.

Comment: @Quercus Added code.

Comment: Your problem is that you serialize it to two different files. `DataContractSerializer` that deserializes books have no idea that there's another one deserializing people and they should reference same objects. Create new class, i.e. `Data` that will hold two collections: `People` and `Books` and serialize\deserialize it - then all cross-references will be correct.

Comment: @Quercus thank you very much. It worked brilliantly!